# Column Operations and eliminating the duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this particular table below . I want to eliminate duplicate Course from the group 2, cause it is in group 1. Basically if the course is mapped on to Group 1 which is mandatory, we have to only consider that and not in any other group. I will have to check repeating courses first and then remove the duplicate course which is not mandatory.

---

```
    Program   Group Course     Mandatory
     Program1   1   a          YES
     Program1   1   b          YES
     Program1   1   c          YES
     Program1   2   d          NO
     Program1   2   a          NO
     Program1   2   e          NO
     Program1   3   f          YES
```

I am not able to figure out same column operations , or my mind is not working today(:-) ) 
I have tried using Count Operation and  creating a flag for duplicate rows ,but cannot do it with 'Group' in the group by clause.

### Output:

```
    Program   Group Course     Mandatory
     Program1   1   a          YES
     Program1   1   b          YES
     Program1   1   c          YES
     Program1   2   d          NO
     Program1   2   e          NO
     Program1   3   f          YES
```

**EDIT**

How can we
Check for duplicate records and delete it from only one particular group.

Comment: If a course shows up in two different groups and neither are mandatory, how should this be handled (or is it even possible)?

Comment: Course can be in mapped on to how many ever groups , but is mandatory in only one Group and not in the rest.There was a glitch in the legacy system, so have to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ROW_NUMBER() function to achieve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COURSE ORDER BY [Group] ) as RowRank
      FROM table
     )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70a0ae/2/0)

Edit:  ROW_NUMBER assigns a number to each row. Numbering will start at 1 for each grouping you assign via the `PARTITION BY` portion, in this case each `COURSE` would have a number 1 and go up.  The order of the numbers is determined by the `ORDER BY` portion, in this case the lowest `[Group]` gets the 1.

Comment: Do you have an example of where it falls apart?  It produces your requested output, but guessing there's a situation not shown in the sample.

Comment: Ya, the above one works fine, and I think I can use this in a lot of queries. Do you use this often? and how reliable in large databases? If possible can you explain the Rowrank command you have written?

Comment: Sure thing, added explanation to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Editing my answer to reflect clarified requirements.

```
select *
from @TableName t
where 
    (Mandatory = 'YES' or 
    not exists (
        select * 
        from @TableName 
        where 
            Program = t.Program and 
            Course = t.Course and 
            [Group] != t.[Group] and 
            Mandatory = 'YES'
    ))
```

based on your comments below here's another sample to try

```
;with group1 as (
    select * from @Table where [Group] = 1
),
groups12 as (
    select * from group1
    union all
    select * from @Table t where [Group] = 2 and not exists (select * from group1 where Program = t.Program and Course = t.Course)
),
groups123 as (
    select * from groups12
    union all
    select * from @Table t where [Group] = 3 and not exists (select * from groups12 where Program = t.Program and Course = t.Course)
),
groups1234 as (
    select * from groups123
    union all
    select * from @Table t where [Group] = 4 and not exists (select * from groups123 where Program = t.Program and Course = t.Course)
)
select * from groups1234
```

This query pulls rows for groups 1-4 in order and only when the Program/Course hasn't already appeared in a lower number group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I cant delete anything from the table itself

Comment: The wording of your question led me to think you were looking for delete. I've updated my answer with a select query that will exclude non-mandatory courses that have a mandatory record for another group.

Comment: Sure. The where clause ensures that each row returned either is Mandatory = 'YES' or if Mandatory = 'NO' that there is no other row with the same Program and Course name for which Mandatory = 'YES'

Comment: Thanks JC. But there was another glitch in the database. There are courses in different groups for the same program which have a mandatory NO ,but the course has to be considered in one of the groups.

Comment: So there are courses in two groups with Mandatory = 'NO' for both? So which do you keep?

Comment: There are 4 Groups for different Programs, Group1: Core ; Group2: Concentration ; Group3: Choice ; Say there are 20 courses. They are mapped differently on all the groups. So courses in Group1 are mandatory and Group2 and Group3 are by choice. So if a course is mapped on to group1 then they should not show up in any other groups and if a course is mapped on Group2 then it should not be counted into group3.

Comment: Is there a way I can just write a procedure to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't need a procedure based on what you're describing. Sounds like you're wanting to start with group 1 and then include the rows for group 2 that aren't already counted then include the rows for group 3 that aren't already counted. In that order of precedence.